Why is there still a bank conflict when using swizzle to process data?
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
__global__ void swizzle_kernel(half *A,half* B){
    __shared__ half s[32][64];
    int lane_id = threadIdx.x % 32;
    int warp_id = threadIdx.x / 32;
    int row = warp_id /4 * 16 + lane_id / 2;
    int col = ((warp_id % 4) * 2 +lane_id % 2) ^ (row & 7);

    *((int4*)(&s[row][col * 8])) = *((int4*)(A + row * 64 + ((warp_id %4) * 2 +lane_id % 2 ) * 8));

    __syncthreads();
    int4 tmp[2];
    tmp[0] =  *(int4*)(&s[warp_id / 4 *16 + lane_id % 16][col * 8]);
    half sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<8;++i){
        sum += tmp[i].x * tmp[i].x;
    }
    B[threadIdx.x] = sum;
}
int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<half[]> h_a(new half[2048]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        for(int j=0;j< 8;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<8;k++){
                h_a[i * 64 + j* 8 + k] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    half* A,*B,*result;
    cudaMalloc(&A,2048*sizeof(half));
    cudaMalloc(&B,256*sizeof(half));
    cudaMemcpy(A,h_a.get(),2048*sizeof(half),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMallocHost(&result,2048*sizeof(half));
    swizzle_kernel<<<1,256>>>(A,B);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpyAsync(result,B,256*sizeof(half),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        std::cout << "result = " << __half2float(result[i]) << std::endl;
    cudaFree(A);
    cudaFree(B);
    cudaFreeHost(result);
    return 0;
}

shared memory content:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

I implemented a simple half-type swizzle in my own way, but I don't know why there is still a bank conflict, and the data I print from the shared memory shows that every 16byte of data is stored in a different bank, why is that?
I'd like to understand why there are bank conflicts and how shared memory works.


Please don't tag multiple different languages, only the one you're actually work in. Which in your case is C++, that is very different from C. Besides that, please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

This is an out of bounds error:
for(int i=0; i<8;++i){ sum += tmp[i].x * tmp[i].x; } tmp has only 2 entries. Also accessing fixed sized arrays dynamically moves then out of registers and into local memory (aka main memory, albeit backed by L1).

You're right, but I just don't want the compiler to optimize the code where I read shared memory.

That table in Nsight Compute tends to include bank conflicts coming from other sources (not sure, maybe global memory accesses hitting L1). Conflicts that come from your shared memory accesses and therefore can be fixed are the ones appearing in the "Source" tab as "L1 Wavefront Shared Excessive". See e.g. Bank Conflicts on Ampere (Nvidia Developer Forums)

thanks，I've read some of the links below, but my native language is not English, so it may be a bit difficult to understand the details, and I don't see a workable and understandable solution to solve this problem; https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/bank-conflicts-on-ampere/240399，https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/shared-memory-bank-conflicts-and-nsight-metric/115731https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/allocating-more-share-memory-than-needed-resulted-in-bank-conflict/310330/5。

I give the following way to implement GEMM with MMA without bank conflict, https://github.com/Bruce-Lee-LY/cuda_hgemm/blob/master/src/mma/mma_permuted.cu, so do you know how to solve this difference?

@Johan apart from the correctness issue, that loop will pretty much certainly be unrolled due to the compile-time know range of it. So local memory should not be an issue (#pragma unroll could be used when paranoid). One correct way of doing the loop is type punning using memcpy (which the compiler will elide): half htmp[8]; memcpy(htmp, &tmp, sizeof tmp); for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { sum += htmp[i] * htmp[i]; }.

Have I answered your question? If yes, please consider accepting my answer so the question is marked as completed.

After some experimentation my working hypothesis is that vectorized shared memory access is handled in the memory controller by sequentially serving chunks of consecutive lanes. I.e. as OP is accessing 4 banks per lane, the memory controller will serve in chunks of 32 / 4 = 8 lanes. Therefore these chunks of 8 lanes are not allowed to have bank conflicts among each other which is the case with OP's layout.
Without knowing exactly what OP is trying to achieve with the current layout I can't formulate the ideal alternative, but both the naive ordering
int row = warp_id * 4 + lane_id / 8;
int col = lane_id % 8;

and a swizzled version
int row = warp_id * 4 + lane_id / 8;
int col = (lane_id % 8) ^ (row & 7);

work without any bank conflicts (according to Nsight Compute) as there is no conflicts among the 8-lane chunks. This also disproves Johan's assumption that accessing multiple banks per lane will always result in bank conflicts (as defined by Nvidia's tooling).

It's easy to see why you have a bank conflict.
Shared memory has 32 integer sized write ports per warp.
Each write port can write to/read from a different address on the same cycle*) if no (x = address % 32, y = address) resolves to the same x, but a different y.
Duplicate addresses never generate bank conflicts.
You have thread 0 accessing slot 0, 1, 2, 3
Thread 1 accessing slot 4,5,6,7
...
Thread 8 accessing slot 32,33,34,35
This means T8 and T0 try and use the same port, a bank conflict.
I'm not sure how int4 is handled, but a warp can only handle (read/write) 32 ints to shared memory every 2 cycles (every 2 cycles, because (on current hardware) the 32 threads in a warp are backed by 16 integer cores).
Because you write int4 sized blocks, you first write ints 0, 4, 8, ... to shared memory. This gives you 4 bank conflicts every write.
If you write out the data as 0,1,2,... then you get no bank conflicts.
Writing out int4 sized chunks is a good idea when writing to main memory, because these writes are fire-and-forget, but to shared memory it does not work due to the bank conflicts.

When using vectorization to store or read data, we only need to care about whether there is a bank conflict when the current 128byte of data is read. So when I read instructions with a 128byte vectorized vector, there is theoretically no bank conflict according to my shared memory layout, which is also written in many forums. For example, these links include:https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass/discussions/1130;https://leimao.github.io/blog/CUDA-Shared-Memory-Swizzling/.

Cutlass works on tensor cores, these have use different instructions, so they are not equivalent to your code, your second link explicitly says sizeof(T) == 4, so int sized data, just like my answer.

That's when I used MMA to compute the matrix product with Tensor Cores. I tried it again just now, and there is no problem with what I said before, that is, when using 128byte to fetch data, there will be no bank conflict in the following way.
__global__ void kernel(half* d_a,half* d_b){
    __shared__ half s[32][64];
    int lane_id = threadIdx.x % 32;int warp_id = threadIdx.x / 32;int row = warp_id * 4 + lane_id / 8;int col = lane_id % 8;*(int4*)(&s[row][col*8]) = *(((int4*)(d_a)) + threadIdx.x);int4 tmp;tmp = *(int4*)(&s[row][((col + 1)%8)*8]);*((int4*)(d_b) + threadIdx.x) = tmp;
}

My understanding is that the "conflicts" due to vectorized access don't count as conflicts as they don't decrease throughput. So one could say that a real conflict is one where at least one bank is underutilized. I'm not 100% sure but I thought that Nsight Compute interprets it that way.

That interpretation naturally only works out if these big requests are cleverly time-sliced in hardware instead of first fetching the first element for each thread, then the second for each thread etc. as assumed in this answer.

Yes, that's why I wonder why there is a bank conflict in my above layout, where 8 threads vectorized access to a column that was originally on columns 0-7, that is, eight consecutive data with the same content, are distributed on different banks in eight rows, there will be conflicts.

Turns out the time-slicing is not clever enough for OP's scheme but it does happen. See my answer.

__global__ void swizzle_kernel(half *A,half* B){
    
    __shared__ half s[32][64];
    int lane_id = threadIdx.x % 32;
    int warp_id = threadIdx.x / 32;
    int row = warp_id /4 * 16 + lane_id % 16 ;
    int col = ((warp_id % 4) * 2 +lane_id/ 16) ^ (row & 7);

    *((int4*)(&s[row][col * 8])) = *((int4*)(A + row * 64 + ((warp_id % 4) * 2 +lane_id / 16 ) * 8));

    __syncthreads();
    int4 tmp;
    tmp =  *((int4*)(&s[((warp_id+1)%8) / 4 *16 + lane_id / 2 ][col * 8]));

While the above distribution of data and threads is theoretically free of bank conflict, when I try to prioritize the layout of both data and threads, the bank conflict disappears. So my answer for the time being is to keep the thread and shared memory layout clean, so maybe the compiler will better optimize the code.

But the load directive was changed to 32-bit loading and there is still a bank conflict, so I guess maybe __syncthreads() didn't work the corresponding role? Or for other reasons. After adjusting the layout of the store, the conflict also disappears and is converted to a 128 bit load instruction, sometimes the bank conflict disappears even if the load is not adjusted, I guess it is that after the store bank conflict, the read instruction will be optimized by the compiler?
